# Enable debug or trace logging on Kublet for Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

Looking at the [Kubernetes dev documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/devel/sig-instrumentation/logging.md) I can see that there is additional logging available for a node. Utimately i'm trying to enable debug or trace logging on Kublet so that I can troubleshoot an issue i'm having. I can't seem to find any guidance anywhere on adjusting this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to pass -v=5 flag on the command line to the kubelet ?

> /usr/bin/kubelet -v=5
>   --bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf ...

If you run kubelet as service with systemd you can adjust it in through unit file:

```
/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf
```